# How to select/click cursors/icon on a map. Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am facing a problem with selenium IDE

I want to select/click any 2 cursors on map page

I can't use the id's because every time you refresh the map you will get another different cursors with different id's, till now i was able to select/click only one cursor on map and I can't select another different one
I used

```
|clickAt | //map/area/ | |
```

&

```
|clickAt | //map/area/ | |
```

to click at one cursor
so please help me to be able to click another

All cursor details:

---

```
map id="gmimap208" name="gmimap208">
<area log="miw" coords="11,0,12,1,13,2,14,3,14,4,14,5,14,6,14,7,14,8,14,9,14,10,13,11,12,12,12,13,11,14,10,15,10,16,9,17,9,18,8,19,7,20,7,20,7,19,6,18,6,17,5,16,4,15,4,14,3,13,2,12,2,11,1,10,1,9,0,8,0,7,0,6,0,5,1,4,1,3,2,2,2,1,4,0,11,0" shape="poly" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
</map>

<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 15px; height: 21px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; left: 373px; top: 370px; z-index: 2000;">
<img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 15px; height: 21px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="/img/property_icons/free/normal.png" draggable="false" usemap="#gmimap226">
<map id="gmimap226" name="gmimap226">
```

---

a cursor XPath :

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[50]/map/area
```

---

a cursor CSS :

```
html.win body.rtl div.content-for-layout div#page-container table tbody tr td div#Map div div div div div div.gmnoprint map#gmimap83 area
```

---

a cursor HTML :

```
<area log="miw" coords="11,0,12,1,13,2,14,3,14,4,14,5,14,6,14,7,14,8,14,9,14,10,13,11,12,12,12,13,11,14,10,15,10,16,9,17,9,18,8,19,7,20,7,20,7,19,6,18,6,17,5,16,4,15,4,14,3,13,2,12,2,11,1,10,1,9,0,8,0,7,0,6,0,5,1,4,1,3,2,2,2,1,4,0,11,0" shape="poly" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: any particular reason why you are using IDE rather than webdriver or rc with a language?

Comment: also rc is not getting support any more (except for maintainence). use webdriver instead

Comment: hi. thanks for trying help me
i use selenium ide because i'm still beginner 
and i'm not good at any programming language yet

Comment: do you want a sustainable, scalable framework?

Comment: @amadain as in selenium ide we can test using axis path in maps so mai hanafy would be trying.

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking at the first  element twice. 
You can specify which element to click on:
//map/area[1]
//map/area[2]
Should get you the first two.